# How does sodium borate (Borax) function to promote Fe-Fe bonding?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metallurgy

Borax is used as "flux" during metal forging to help stick two pieces of steel together. I am curious what is happening at the atomic level. How does the addition of borax promote Fe-Fe bond formation?

Comment: What is 'flux' usually mean for soldering and brazing? Why do you not consider Borax suitable for that?

Comment: "stick two pieces of steel together" isn't equal to  "promote Fe-Fe bond formation". You're making there some assumptions that seem rather too far fetched.

Comment: Hint: think about air, and why it could cause issues.